# How can this html submit a form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, capybara

I have a form defined as

```
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_7" action="/service-sign-up/user-agreement" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Much further beneath this on the same page there is the submit button:

```
<a data-submit-form="true" data-form-id="account-details-form" class="btn btn-lg btn-grn" role="button" href="#">Next Step</a>
```

This link (`<a href="#">`) is not within the `<form>` element, it is at the very bottom of the page.

How can the `<a href="#" ...>` element submit the form? Is this an AJAX call?

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery to submit form:

```
<a data-submit-form="true" data-form-id="account-details-form" class="btn btn-lg btn-grn" role="button" href="#" id="btn_next">Next Step</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_next").click(function(){
    $(".edit_user").submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery the only way to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Html Form

```html
   

<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "action_page.php".</p>
```

Comment: This does not answer my question.